# How To Make A Basic Palm Tree

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, texturing, blender-internal-render-engine, shaders

How would i go about making something like this [image]

And this [image] was my attempt at making some palm trees :(

I want a method of making a palm tree that looks a lot better then my attempt.

Comment: While typing "blender palm tree" on google, the first result is [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DCVqOSRT91I), which perfectly correspond to you question. Please make some researches before asking.

Comment: thank you  Aleph that was helpful be sure to make it your answer.